# Python access to SQL Server 2008

Tags: python, sql-server-2008, pyodbc

I would like to access to SQL server with python to do some data manipulation.

The SQL Server is on a Small Business Server SBS2011 and contains a Database that is used by the company with all business data that our ERP uses.

I have installed pyodbc and readed the example:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=testdb;UID=me;PWD=pass')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
```

But the problem is that i have no idea of what to use as SERVER and DATABASE parameters... code example are general...
Should I put the directory of the local net SBS2011 server? Should it be the IP:port like 192.168.0.3:1441?
Where I can find them?
Any clue?

Thanks in advance

---

I could retrieve this info into the server surfing into the software "Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio"

I didn't understand the mechanism that underlines the connection but this works:

```
import pyodbc
server="SBS2011"
user="sa"
database="topimpresa_web" //the database i want to access
connectionString='DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=%s;DATABASE=%s;UID=%s;PWD=<secret>' % (server,database,user)
```

Comment: Ok, so you have it working now?

Answer (score 3):

Typically the SERVER would be the name of the machine running SBS2011 and DATABASE would be the name of your company's database. What have you tried? Are you getting an error message?

Answer (score 3):

its simple.

```
import pyodbc

dsn = 'sqlserverdatasource'
user = '<username>'
password = '<password>'
database = '<dbname>'

con_string = 'DSN=%s;UID=%s;PWD=%s;DATABASE=%s;' % (dsn, user, password, database)
conn = pyodbc.connect(con_string)
```